# How can I define a complex entity in API.AI like service request number

Tags: dialogflow-es

I need to make an entity service order but the format should be date-XXXXXX i.e.  170717-000001.

Date in simple format followed by hyphen and then a six digit number. Ho can I create a complex entity like this.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, API.AI does not support regex but you can use @sys.any to catch strings and validate them at your backend.